# Spring boot webclient calling api which returns XML response having 2GB best way to call

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am calling a api which returns xm response , but that response has around 2GB data , could you please  help how should we call that in efficient way , now its failing to databuffer limit exceeds

below is the XML dto class

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Result")
    @lombok.Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Result{
     private List<Data> dataLisst;
    
    }

@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
@lombok.Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Data {

    private Integer id;
    private String dataVersion;
    private String name;
}
```

Below is the way i am calling Webclient its mono object response

```
@Service
public class WebclientXML {

    public Result getXMLResult() {
        return  getWebClient()
                .get()
                .uri("/xml-resp/res")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Result.class)
                .block();
    }

    private WebClient getWebClient() {
         return  WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://<host>:port")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you don't want to marshal 2GB of data into memory, you need to using *streaming* when handling the response body. You should do your own *research* for how to do that: Keyword `streaming`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your remote service responds with a collection of POJOs that Jackson can deserialize as Something.class, you can do something like:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/streaming", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Flux<Something> streamSomething() {
  return WebClient.create()
    .get().uri("http://example.org/resource")
    .retrieve().bodyToFlux(Something.class)
    .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
    .repeat();
}
```

Comment: Its not collection of Pojo , it simple object like below sample response ``<Result>
<data>agaga</data>
<data>ww</data>
</Result>``